# First move after homing way too fast

Tags: marlin, creality-ender-3

There are a few hits on my issue title but could not find an actual answer/advice.
I burned my Ender 3 Pro Creality motherboard and replaced it with an SKR 1.4 + TMC 2209 + BLTouch.
Everything is moving like it should and calibrated.

However, at the end of the homing process, the Z-axis goes up, then it's supposed to move to the printing position.
At that point, the acceleration is so great that the Z-axis barely goes down and I end up printing about 4 cm above the bed.

These are the settings I changed on my Marlin 2.0.7 firmware in relation to the Ender 3 setup:

```
Configuration.h
set #define STRING_CONFIG_H_AUTHOR "Nicolas Rietsch v 0.1.2"
enable #define CUSTOM_MACHINE_NAME
set #define CUSTOM_MACHINE_NAME "Ender-3 PRO"
set #define TEMP_SENSOR_BED 1
set #define DEFAULT_MAX_FEEDRATE          { 500, 500, 5, 45 }
set #define DEFAULT_MAX_ACCELERATION      { 450, 450, 100, 10000 }
set #default DEFAULT_ACCELERATION          450
set #define DEFAULT_TRAVEL_ACCELERATION   500 

set #define INVERT_X_DIR true
set #define INVERT_E0_DIR true
set #define X_MIN_POS -26
set #define X_BED_SIZE 230
set #define Y_BED_SIZE 230
set #define Z_MAX_POS 250
enable #define NOZZLE_PARK_FEATURE
```

```
Configuration_adv.h
set #define X_CURRENT       500
set #define Y_CURRENT       500
set #define Z_CURRENT       500
set #define E0_CURRENT      650
set #define CHOPPER_TIMING CHOPPER_DEFAULT_24V
```

What am I missing?

Comment: DEFAULT_MAX_ACCELERATION... what is your current value for Z in EEPROM? Have you checked acceleration settings using LCD or g-code? Or reset to defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it would it help if you fix `#default` to `#define` in the current line:

```
set #default DEFAULT_ACCELERATION ...
```